# Playing MMS streams within Python

Tags: python, streaming, pyqt, audio-streaming, mms

I'm writing a XM desktop application (I plan on releasing the source on github when I'm finished if anyone is interested) Anyway, the one part I know very little about is how to play media within Python (I'm using PyQt for the frontend). Basically, I have a mms:// url that I need to play. I was wondering if there is a library that could accomplish this or something, really I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

I know its possible, because SMplayer (Python implementation of MPlayer that uses Qt) works with MMS, I may have to take a peak at they're source if worse comes to worse.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at

1. [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/)
2. [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/)
3. [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/)

[Here is a code snippet](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet467.html#) of doing a similar thing with wxPython.

All of these can play media files.