# python - 'requests' HTTP library - get response for non HTTP audio stream URLs having mms protocol

Tags: python, http-headers, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get response (to check response header content-type) for audio streamURL: mms://186.65.90.12:8080/listen.pls.. and I am getting following error:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("mms://186.65.90.12:8080/listen.pls",stream=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 279, in request
resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 373, in send
adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 385, in get_adapter
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'mms://186.65.90.12:8080/listen.pls'
```

Is 'requests' HTTP library capable of handling non HTTP URLs? If not, are there any alternatives to make it work? I already tried urllib2 with no luck..

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072652/playing-mms-streams-within-python

Comment: You can [add additional transports](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) but you'd have to code your own MMS transport for the `requests` library.

Comment: To follow Martijn, you'd need to implement a MMS transport adapter. [Here](https://lukasa.co.uk/2012/12/Writing_A_Transport_Adapter/)'s an example of me doing this for FTP.

Comment: @Lukasa: Thanks for your response..in python..Is there any alternate way which would simply return response-header and the respomse-content for MMS audio stream-> mms://186.65.90.12:8080/listen.pls..I understand that writing my own MMS transport adaptor might help me in getting customized solution..but before doing that I want to confirm if thats the only solution to this..

Comment: @SagarG: I don't know of anything off the top of my head, so you should investigate the answer that Pawel Piecyk linked to.